# ActiveRecord getting n most recent item?

Tags: mysql, activerecord

I have a table of the following:

```
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user      | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content   | varchar(512) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| location  | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What would be the most efficient way to select the *n* most recent post using an ActiveRecord query? i.e given a variable n = 9, i would want the 9th most recent post.

Comment: Are you talking about Rails ActiveRecord ORM?

Answer (score 1):

If yuo need the first 9 You could use limit 9..

```
select  * from my_table 
order by timestamp desc
limit 9
```

or if you need  only the 9th use limit 8,1

```
select  * from my_table 
order by timestamp desc
limit 8,1
```

Comment: I guess you mean limit 8,1 for *9th most recent post*

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `offset`.  For example, to get the 3rd book, use `offset(2)`:

```
irb(main):010:0> Book.order(created_at: :asc).limit(3).map &:author
=> ["Steven B. Sample", "Victor H. Krulak", "Steven F. Hayward"]
irb(main):011:0> Book.order(created_at: :asc).offset(2).first.author
=> "Steven F. Hayward"
```